# How to call Jquery on On Click event

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

Unable to Call jquery Function on Onclick Event.

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
    <style>
    .step_box {
        border: 1.0px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
        border-radius: 10.0px 10.0px 10.0px 10.0px;
    }
    .step_box:hover, #selected_step_box, .QuickStartLong:hover {
        background: rgb(184, 225, 252) !important;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$("step_box").click(function() {
        alert('Welcome!');
        j$('.step_box').css('background-color', '#ffffff'); });
    </script>
    <a class="step_box"  > <span>This is Section 1</span></a>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot the DOT (.) to indicate a class in the jQuery selector. Change it to `j$(".step_box").click( function()........`

Comment: Already Tried  `j$(".step_box").click( function()` . However that is also not working.

Comment: Try changing the <a class="step_box"  > <span>This is Section 1</span></a> to <a class="step_box"  >This is Section 1</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. I was missing    *j$(document).ready(function() { }*

`<script>
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
*j$(document).ready(function() {*
  //initialize our interface
 j$("step_box").click(function() {
    alert('Welcome!');
    j$('.step_box').css('background-color', '#ffffff'); });
 });
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Move your `<script>` tag to below the `<a>` tag.
Because you are not using an onload/ready function, this code will be executed from top to bottom.
When you call the jQuery click function, the `<a>` tag does not exist yet.

Oh and you need that dot in the jQuery selector - add that too. 
Finally, I always define my pages something like this:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0"
showHeader="false" >
```

when testing, as it removes the potential for any conflicts from Salesforce built in styles.

Here's the full working source if you want it:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0"
showHeader="false" >
    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
    <style>
    .step_box {
        border: 1.0px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
        border-radius: 10.0px 10.0px 10.0px 10.0px;
    }
    .step_box:hover, #selected_step_box, .QuickStartLong:hover {
        background: rgb(184, 225, 252) !important;
    }
    </style>

    <a class="step_box"  > <span>This is Section 1</span></a>

    <script>
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
    j$(".step_box").click(function() {
        alert('Welcome!');
        j$('.step_box').css('background-color', '#ffffff'); });
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Great - the ready function is probably a good way to go too. The main thing is to understand what is happening with the page eh.